# GCloud SSH tunnel to localhost

Tags: networking, ssh, gcloud

I'm trying to create a localhost SSH forwarding from GCLOUD VM instance, because I need to use my K8S cluster as a proxy for external mongodb database.

For better description:

```
[ MongoDB client ] ----> [ SSH tunnel via localhost ] -----> [ gcloud VM instance ] -----> [ MongoDB instance within same VPC network ]
```

I followed [tutorial Set up SSH tunnel for private browsing using GCE](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-tunnel-on-gce)

```sh
gcloud compute instances create --zone europe-west3-a tunnel

gcloud compute ssh --zone europe-west3-a tunnel -- -N -p 22 -D localhost:5000
```

Next I want to connect via localhost:

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine myusername@localhost -p 5000`
and I'm getting `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

also I tried:
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine myusername@myusername-MBP -p 5000`
getting: `ssh: connect to host amirs-mbp port 5000: Connection refused`

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out this:

1. Following the [original tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-tunnel-on-gce) I have created VM and forwarded as I mentioned in previous question

`gcloud compute ssh --zone europe-west3-a tunnel -- -N -p 22 -D localhost:5000`

2. I have created SOCKS connection as described in the tutorial under section Set up the proxy
3. Using RoboMongo I connected directly to a MongoDB without using SSH tunnel.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.